# Do the same multi task in the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem in Asp.net C#

I have the code below :
    List objectList = new List();

```
foreach(var item in listItem)
{
  object obj = getData (item);
  objectList.add(obj);
}
Console.Write("Finish all");
```

Each time `getData (item);' fires it takes about 1s;

I want all items in `listItem` to run at the same time and then execute after `foreach` finishes the `Console.write("Finish all")`

How can I do that?

Any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: invoke the function in a separate thread?

Comment: That's like saying How can I optimise something I'm not going to show you....Not a real question. Why does running aaa() take 1 second?

Comment: @MitchWheat but I thinks his question is right, it doesn't matter what's happening inside aaa() he doesn't want to optimize aaa(), he wants some parallel solution which is a good question I think.

Comment: @MitchWheat aaa() take 1second, it the best, sorry because i can't not  share what aaa() do here, and, thanks for your help.

Comment: aaa() i want to get item from server (out of control) but the server response to low.After that i add that item into another list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        int itemCount = ItemList.Count;

             List<object> objectList = new List<object>();
            ManualResetEvent[] resetEvents = new ManualResetEvent[itemCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
            {

                var item= ItemList[i];

                resetEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((object index) =>
                {
                    ItemCalEvent item = getData(item);

                    lock (objectList)
                        objectList.Add(item);

                    resetEvents[(int)index].Set();
                }), i);
            }
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(resetEvents);
```

This is good in .net 3.5

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Parallel.Foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx).Where each iterations may run in parallel.

Comment: +1. Also it will put significant burden to make code thread safe (as any other mulithreaded suggestion here) and will have unknown imapct on other requests to the same server.

Comment: I'm using .net 3.5, Paralllel not exists

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) to get it done:

```
 var tasks = listItem.Select(item => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => aaa()));
 Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

 Console.Write();
```

If you don't need to wait all tasks finish, just skip `WaitAll`:

```
 var tasks = listItem.Select(item => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => aaa()));
 Console.Write();
```

For .NET 3.5, you can use ThreadPool:

```
 listItem.ForEach(item => ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => aaa()));
 Console.Write();
```

Comment: I using .net 3.5, have any other way, because Task if only for .net 4

Comment: state => aaa();
"state" is? i try but it error.
aaa() do like this: 
{object obj= "This take 1second"; objectList.add(obj);}

Comment: state => aaa(), state i think have not been defined

Answer (score 5):

```
 using System.Threading;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
 foreach(item in listItem)
 {
       tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => aaa()));
 }
// If you want the Console.Writeline to execute immediately after starting the tasks
Console.Writeline();            
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
Console.Writeline("Finised executing all tasks");
```

---

And if you want use Threads to do this, you can:

```
List<ManualResetEvent> resetEvents = new List<ManualResetEvent>();
.
.
.


 foreach(item in lisItem)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(aaa));
                ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                resetEvents.Add(resetEvent);
                thread.Start(resetEvent);

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(resetEvents.ToArray<WaitHandle>());
            Console.WriteLine("Finised executing all threads");


        }

}
.
.
.

    void aaa(object data)
    {
        ManualResetEvent resetEvent = data as ManualResetEvent;
        // completed execution
        Console.WriteLine(".");
        resetEvent.Set();
    }
```

Comment: using System.Threading.Tasks;
I can not find Threading.Tasks, what i wrong?

Comment: I using .net 3.5, have any other way, because Task if only for .net 4

Comment: The first, thank you very much for your help.
But i'm not clear. Sorry because i'm new bee..

aaa() function just 2 line:
  object obj= "This take 1second";
  objectList.add(obj);

So, how can i do with your code.

Hope you help me again. Thank you very much!